# RecycleView подсвечивание нажатого элемента

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Подскажите, как правильно сделать подсвечивание нажатого элемента в RecycleView, чтобы после нажатия выделение пропадало и выполнялось некое действие. Сейчас список построен и для каждого элемента RecycleView имеется отдельный цвет, для RecycleView itemrow установлен селектор(возможно он не нужен).

```
 android:background="@drawable/selector_recycleview"
```

Написан адаптер:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UslugiAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.rl2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.rl1.setBackgroundColor(helper.getColor(mContext,R.color.lightGray));
            holder.rl2.setBackgroundColor(helper.getColor(mContext,R.color.lightGray));
        }
    });
    holder.tv_name.setText(entriesList.get(position).getFirst());
    holder.tv_desc.setText(entriesList.get(position).getSecond());
    if (position==1){
        holder.rl1.setBackgroundColor(helper.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorGRAYSer1));
        holder.rl2.setBackgroundColor(helper.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorGRAYSer2));
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(helper.getDrawableName(mContext,entriesList.get(position).getThird())).into(holder.iv_logo);
    }
    if (position==2){
        holder.rl1.setBackgroundColor(helper.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorBlueSer1));
        holder.rl2.setBackgroundColor(helper.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorBlueSer2));
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(helper.getDrawableName(mContext,entriesList.get(position).getThird())).into(holder.iv_logo);
    }
```

}

Сделал выделение через holder.rl2.setOnClickListener, но оно не пропадает после нажатия. Дальше уже начал какие-то грабли городить... Скорей всего что-то упускаю. Прошу помочь!
**EDIT**
selector_recycleview

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/lightGray" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Разметка Itemа

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/selector_recycleview"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="101dp"
    >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/someview555"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorLightBlue"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/someview555"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/tow_white70"
                android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView49"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView52"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView49"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто сделайте background-drawable нормальный , а не вручную меняйте цвета,

например:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lightGray" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@color/lightGray" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lightGray" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lightGray" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@color/lightGray" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Указал свой нормальный background-drawable в вопросе. Это неверное решение. Там, где я вручную указываю цвета это так и должно быть, иначе никак не добиться установленных цветов для RecycleView Item'ов.

Comment: разметку item в студию

Comment: меняйте цвет у дочернего RelativeLayout a background оставьте у парента

Comment: Пробовал и так тоже, не помогает!

Comment: тогда уже становится непонятным чего именно вы хотите добиться

Comment: Изначально элемент уже выделен и после нажатия выделение должно исчезнуть?

Comment: Нет, изначально построен список с элементами разного цвета, если цвет не назначаю через адаптер, то выделение через селектор работает. Как только назначаю цвет в адаптере, то перестает работать.

Comment: ну скорее всего из-за того что метод setBackgoundColor заменяет селектор

Comment: Получается, что если вы захотите задать цвета для различных элементов списка по умолчанию, и при этом отслеживать нажатие по ним, то это не реализуемая задача?

Comment: ну можно сделать дочерний элемент и ему цвета менять, а селектор на паренте оставить, первое что в голову приходит